# Chat rooms are not receiving question feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed, outage

There seems to be something preventing question feeds from appearing in chat.

For one example, [the Code Review chat room's feed subscriptions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8595/the-2nd-monitor?tab=feeds) include [Recent Questions - Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/feeds) and [Recent Questions - Code Review Meta Stack Exchange](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds), but no chat messages have been relayed from either feed since approximately 2016-06-07T19:08:00Z.

Comment: it is happening in different [arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11674/question-feeds-seem-to-be-broken) chat rooms as well.

Comment: Review queues were empty (on the 4 sites I can access them on) a few hours ago as well, I wonder if it was related...

Comment: Mos Eisley has lost our dearly not-beloved Obie.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/bf5KB.png

Comment: The PPCG new sandboxed posts feed is also borked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scheduler was not running properly for chat.se - we gave it a kick, so it should be fine now.

Comment: I admire your kicks.