# Users not being dropped from chat sidebar list

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Normally, after your session is closed and a certain period of inactivity, you're dropped from the chat sidebar:

[image: The 2nd Monitor]

However, it seems they're not being dropped from the sidebar list.

Perhaps this is linked to the [chat feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280034/chat-rooms-are-not-receiving-question-feeds) not updating (a schedular bug?)

My suspicions lead me to believe this is only affecting Stack Exchange chat, not MSE or SO chat.

Comment: I just left the Tavern manually, did I drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side effect of the scheduler not running on chat.se.com - all better now.